# Tmux + python input() -- control characters taken literally

Tags: python, input, console, tmux

I'm trying to get a simple console input in Python (`query = input('>>> ')`). However, when I run this code inside Tmux, any control characters are taken literally, so I can't hit Enter to finish the input (prints `^M` instead) or break the process (prints `^C`).

When the code is run outside of Tmux, it works fine. Any ideas?

Comment: what's the value of `$TERM` outside of tmux? and what's the value inside tmux?

Comment: It's `xterm-256color` outside and `screen-256color` inside, but changing that has no effect.